# Brother Labelprinter. Bluetooth vs AirPrint

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I need to connect my app to a label printer. I have landed on a Brother. So, as far as I can see I have to choose QL810W with AirPrint, or QL820NWB with BlueTooth.

Is there a difference in the integration between the two? Is one or the other easier to integrate with swift?

Comment: To my understanding, in order for an app to be able to access a printer, the printer needs to be able to connect to your device. Due to this, I would have to say that AirPrint will be a better option for you as Apple devices only recognize printers if they're AirPrint enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use AirPrint with both of these printers, I probably wouldn't for a couple of reasons:

1. AirPrint always shows a confirmation screen that requires the user to select a printer and confirm the print; This is typically not the desired flow when using a label printer
2. AirPrint uses a fairly generic driver, so you won't get the same control over page size that you get with the Brother SDK.

Brother provides an SDK that supports both of these printers via WiFi (and Bluetooth on the 820).

There are some pros & cons regarding Bluetooth & WIFI:

- For WIFI to work the iOS device and the printer need to be on the same WIFI network.  For a permanent installation this may not be a problem, but it may be an issue if you need to move around
- The Bluetooth connection uses an MFi connection and the external connectivity framework.  You need to submit a request to Brother to authorise your app's use of their MFi identifier before Apple can approve your app.

Comment: It's crucial that the label printing should run in the background. It should print without any interaction from the user after a confirmation button is pressed on the app. Is Bluetooth the only way to go to get background printing?

Comment: No, as long as you use the Brother SDK you can use WIFI or Bluetooth. Either way there will be a one-time setup in your app where the user will need to select the printer they want to use